# New scrape table data from a hover popup with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, screen-scraping

I had this Selenium hover scrape working a few years ago, and I remember it was a challenge to select the correct hover table element, which only shows on hover. The website has undergone a complete style overhaul (seems like Tailwind CSS), and even though I've used the inspector w/a forced hover state, now Selenium says that the hover table I want to scrape is either not an element that it recognizes, or it is not an interactable element, depending on which selector I choose. All of my other modifications have found the updated elements just fine. How can I solve either or both of these issues for the present and the future? Cheers

Image of hover:
[image]

Sample Code (and error):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="config/chromedriver")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 50)
action = ActionChains(driver)
driver.get("https://www.oddsportal.com/tennis/australia/wta-australian-open/jimenez-kasintseva-victoria-lys-eva-IVZa5PVf/")

#first_td = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//tr[@class='lo odd']/td[2]")))
#ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(first_td).perform()

tool_tip_text = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#tooltip").get_attribute('innerText')
print(tool_tip_text)

"""Error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#tooltip"}"""
```

Desired Output:

```
20 Sep, 17:42 2.30 +0.03
20 Sep, 17:29 2.27 +0.02
20 Sep, 17:25 2.25 -0.20
20 Sep, 17:24 2.45 +0.20
20 Sep, 17:20 2.25 -0.20
20 Sep, 17:19 2.45 +0.20
20 Sep, 16:58 2.25 -0.20
20 Sep, 16:56 2.45 +0.20
20 Sep, 16:30 2.25 -0.20
20 Sep, 16:29 2.45 +0.18
20 Sep, 16:23 2.27 -0.18
20 Sep, 16:21 2.45 +0.20
20 Sep, 15:52 2.25 -0.20
20 Sep, 15:51 2.45 +0.20
20 Sep, 15:45 2.25 -0.20
20 Sep, 15:42 2.45 +0.20
20 Sep, 15:41 2.25 -0.20
20 Sep, 15:36 2.45 +0.12
20 Sep, 15:16 2.33 -0.12
20 Sep, 15:14 2.45 +0.12

Opening odds:
19 Sep, 19:00 2.33
```

Comment: Almost all the scores shows a different hover table element.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium True - I'm going for the table directly under the 'Betting Exchanges' heading

Answer (score 1):

I can't help with the future, usually I use #ID CSS element hoping devs won't change them if redesigning the page, but that's a bet.
If you're familiar with Python string parsing I would suggest scraping from the whole page after clicking on an  element

```
output = driver.page_source
```

then something like:

```
output.split("Odds movement")[1].split("Opening odds:")[0]
```

[image]